Stop Firefox from polluting the terminal with "Javascript error:"
I've started testing "Firefox Dynasty", a backport of Firefox v132 for legacy Mac OS X versions like 10.9 . It works great but the terminal is being spammed with JavaScript errors.
Typing this message I get the following line for each character (!) I type:
JavaScript error: moz-extension://52cf7294-7e46-924a-ad7a-650104b00232/js/contentscript.js, line 19: TypeError: event is undefined

I'm currently running after launching from a terminal window so I can catch certain fatal errors; I don't care about JS errors that I (probably) can't fix and that don't seem to correspond to any problems.
Is there a way to disable this output and not any other messages? According to about:logging the logging function is actually disabled so I fear that I cannot use the MOZ_LOG variable.
EDIT: just removing the extensions is not an option and AFAIK there's nothing wrong with them because Firefox (v133) doesn't give any of these errors on Linux.
EDIT2: In case anyone is tempted to point it out: I also already know that I could also replace the machine with one that's able to run a regular build of the current Firefox release.
EDIT3: I don't have any extensions that are supposed (or that I want) to be doing something in reaction to each and every keystroke.

Remove whatever extension has the UUID 52cf7294-7e46-924a-ad7a-650104b00232 or (if it's your own) fix the extension. Some of them are listed at about:debugging. All of them should be listed at extensions.webextensions.uuids.

Yeah, it seems unnecessary to mention that wasn't an option...

Why isn't it an option?

Because I use the extensions and they do work as they should AFAICT?

If there's an error in one of them generating continual error messages, I wouldn't say that it's working.

I'd remove all extensions and then add them back one at a time.  Start with the one that is working well, and then see if others cause a software conflict.

Please, I just want to know if there's a way to prevent the messages from being printed, other than sending stdout and stderr to fgrep -v 'JavaScript error:' ...

So I'll answer my own question with what I found going through the code on searchfox.
The offending messages are printed when Firefox is built with fuzzing enabled (I'd hope not) or with -DDEBUG or -DMOZ_ENABLE_JS_DUMP or when the browser.dom.window.dump.enabled about:config setting is true. That one is off for me on Linux, I still have to get back to my Mac to see if it somehow gets set to true in the Dynasty build.
Toggling that setting to Linux gives me the same JS errors, but with the useful addition that it's about event.keyCode, a deprecated property from what I understand (so the error could well be a false alarm).
